# Disable false warning "possible missing interpolator"

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings, string-interpolation

I have some nested case classes, and for a specific serialization mechanism I need to provide a `productPrefix` that contains `$` characters. Like so

```
object Foo {
  case class Bar() {
    override def productPrefix = "Foo$Bar"
  }
}
```

Now I get a compiler warning from this:

> ```
> Warning:(53, 42) possible missing interpolator: detected interpolated identifier `$Bar`
>     override def productPrefix: String = "Foo$Bar"
> ```

Is there a way to disable the warning, if possible only for this instance? Scala version is 2.11.8.

---

**Edit:** I just thought I was clever: `"Foo\u0024Bar"`. But the compiler even warns about this. Another solution is `classOf[Bar].getName`, given the constraint that there are no further outer objects.

Comment: `-Xlint:-missing-interpolator,_`

Comment: @som-snytt Ah! Right, I didn't have `-Xlint` enabled for my other project (that is full of these strings), so I was surprised to see the warning for the first time. In this new project I had `-Xlint` enabled.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If there's a way to compose the string from its parts you could do something like this.

```
override def productPrefix = "Foo$" + "Bar"
```

You could also quiet the "missing interpolator" warning by actually invoking the interpolator, but escaping the `$`.

```
override def productPrefix = f"Foo$$Bar"
```

Comment: Your other answer was pretty clever.

Comment: @som-snytt, I had to rethink it a bit.  I've incorporated it into this answer.

Comment: But that's wrong. See my answer about $$. I meant that `s"Foo$Bar"` works because the object Bar has toString = "Bar".

Comment: But @som-snytt, `s"Foo$Bar"` gets interpolated to `FooBar` and I thought the whole point was to retain the `$` in the result string.

Comment: d'oh, sorry I wasn't paying attention. I'm sure I tried it while waiting for a build to finish! You're right, of course. Maybe I thought I saw it because the ordinary object Foo is "Foo$". Mea culpa. Anyway, the $$ is taken as literal $ in interpolation. :) `s"foo$$baz"`

Comment: "by actually invoking the interpolator" -- double $ works, but it does _not__ insert the `Bar` value, as you indicate with `^^^`. It works by simply escaping the dollar sign.

Comment: Escapes mess with your head. But FTR, use the f-interpolator to get a constant; s-interpolator is not a macro.

Answer (score 7):

The warning is induced by `-Xlint`. The specific linter about the supposedly missing interpolator can be disabled by giving the `scalac` command line option as

```
-Xlint:_,-missing-interpolator
```

The underscore (`_`) is for "everything" and the `-missing-interpolator` is for "except the missing interpolator warning".

Answer (score 4):

`-Xlint` warns if it sees a var in scope:

```
$ scala -Xlint
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> { val x = "hi" ; s"$x" }
res0: String = hi

scala> { val x = "hi" ; "$x" }
<console>:12: warning: possible missing interpolator: detected interpolated identifier `$x`
       { val x = "hi" ; "$x" }
                        ^
res1: String = $x

scala> { val y = "hi" ; "$x" }  // no warning if x is not a symbol
res2: String = $x

scala> object Foo { case class Bar() { override def productPrefix = "Foo$Bar" } }
<console>:11: warning: possible missing interpolator: detected interpolated identifier `$Bar`
       object Foo { case class Bar() { override def productPrefix = "Foo$Bar" } }
                                                                    ^
defined object Foo
```

Usually, use double dollar for literal dollar when interpolating. (Edit: to be clear, `$$` is like `\$`.)

```
scala> object Foo { case class Bar() { override def productPrefix = s"Foo$$Bar" } }
defined object Foo

scala> Foo.Bar().productPrefix
res8: String = Foo$Bar
```

Use f-interpolator to get a constant string.

```
scala> def productPrefix = f"Foo$$Bar"
productPrefix: String

scala> :javap -pv -
[snip]
  public java.lang.String productPrefix();
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: ldc           #16                 // String Foo$Bar
         2: areturn
```

You can also put your funky constants in a quarantined scope:

```
scala> :pa -raw
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

package k {
trait K { final val p = "Foo$Bar" }
}
package q {
  case class Bar() { override def productPrefix = (null: k.K).p }
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.


scala> q.Bar().productPrefix
res1: String = Foo$Bar
```

The constant is inlined. The trick of the null reference avoids any allocations, including any singleton object.

Answer (score 1):

The warning only happens when there is an identifier with that name in  the lexical scope.
In case the linter complains about it when the identifier is a val/var, you could just rename the val/var

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `@nowarn` annotation on the definition:

```
@nowarn("msg=possible missing interpolator")
override def productPrefix = "Foo$Bar"
```

The "missing interpolator" warning is useful in general, so I would not disable it.

Comment: This is by far the best way to go IMO.